# How do I test CSS over many form factors?

Tags: css, browser

I only have a single monitor with a 1920x1080 resolution. Is there some tool that helps me see the outcome of my CSS changes instantly over multiple resolutions? I'm only starting to learn CSS, but constantly resizing my browser into all directions after every tiny modification of my CSS file seems cumbersome.

Comment: I'd recommend not using percentage values, and make your page fit into 1024x768 and larger. This will leave a few people out in the cold, but very few.

Comment: @JamWaffles - What about fluid layouts?

Comment: That's a good exception. I work mainly on fixed-width layouts, but yes, good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good topic about your question, with your monitor, you should be able to test it with this solution http://www.cssgirl.com/resources/2006/05/27/browser-size-check/

Answer (score 2):

The [Web developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) has a built-in option to resize your window. Alternatively, you can also create bookmarklets to resize the window using the `resizeTo` function.

Comment: I was going to suggest the web developer plugin as well, also [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/) will take screenshots of your page on multiple browsers and operating systems.  There are similar services you can pay for that will support various browsers, OS'es and resolutions.

Comment: I thought there was something like BrowserShots out there, but couldn't remember the name.

Comment: Screenshots are usually not enough to *fully* test the page's appearance on a web page. For instance, an element may fall off a page, without noticing. When you resize the window, the developer can interact with the page, and perform tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your dimensions using `px` pixels - you shouldn't need to concern yourself with resolution.

Comment: That's not always the best way of doing it.